# Check consistency between OutLook and IMAP

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap

Hello to the community.

Is there any procedure or  program to continuously (weekly) check the consistency having OutLook and IMAP?

The story behind the question is as follows.

Recently for one of my users, i had to prepare a new computer and subsequently install the IMAP account on OutLook.

The user discovered that thousands of folders and mails, that existed on old OutLook did not exist on the new one.

Further investigation shows us that those folders did not exist on mail server either, only on OutLook client of the old computer.

Obviously OutLook did not synced with IMAP server the archiving of emails to folders, so emails lost from server.

Finally it seems that OST file was corrupted but scanpst or scanost could not repair it and only using a third party tool manage to convert them to maildir format and from there to recover them.

Now i am looking for a way to continuously check the synchronization and prevent it to be catastrophic.

I would appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my experience with IMAP,  it's recommended to log into the web mail deirectly to check what has been synced there, which is usually the same as the server-side.Compared to other programs, it is not automatic but more accurate.